# Using angular to detect when a user leaves/enters a syntax block, and perform action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create an interface on my web application where a user can input LaTeX math or code blocks. I would like to update a "preview" block in real time to show them the results of their action. I would have some syntax blocks to denote math blocks (eg `[math][/math]`).

The goal is to see when they either leave or enter these blocks. When they leave the block, the preview will render it. When they enter the block, it will *unrender* it. I want to use KaTeX to render their math as LaTeX in the preview.

Unfortunately, I'm really not very far:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form method="POST" action="/api/v1/article" role="form">
        <textarea placeholder="write here" ng-model="article.content" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="article-preview">
      {{ article.content }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then my controller is really just at its most basic level right now.

```
articleController.controller('write', ['$scope', 'Article',
  function($scope, Article) {
    article = {};
  }
]);
```

I imagine I need a directive, as well as some kind of `$scope.$on` type of event to make this happen, and some directive for  How could this work?

Comment: Data-binding? `ng-model`?

Comment: `<textarea ng-change="userIsTyping()" ng-blur="userLeftTextarea()">`